# Modifying warnings that seems to come from nowhere

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, rasa-nlu

I forked a repository named `rasa_nlu` to work on a part of the code I want to modify : there is a function `component.train(...)` inside of a function `train(...)` in a file [`model.py`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/model.py) which seems to trigger warnings without providing the origin and I want to find what trigger it.

Basically it applies this function to a list of components:

```
[<rasa_nlu.utils.spacy_utils.SpacyNLP object at 0x7f3abbfbd780>, <rasa_nlu.tokenizers.spacy_tokenizer.SpacyTokenizer object at 0x7f3abbfbd710>, <rasa_nlu.featurizers.spacy_featurizer.SpacyFeaturizer object at 0x7f3abbfbd748>, <rasa_nlu.featurizers.regex_featurizer.RegexFeaturizer object at 0x7f3abbd1a630>, <rasa_nlu.extractors.crf_entity_extractor.CRFEntityExtractor object at 0x7f3abbd1a748>, <rasa_nlu.extractors.entity_synonyms.EntitySynonymMapper object at 0x7f3abbd1a3c8>, <rasa_nlu.classifiers.sklearn_intent_classifier.SklearnIntentClassifier object at 0x7f3abbd1a240>]
```

And it seems that the last one triggers the warnings.

I tried to modify the function `train()` in the [`components.py`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/components.py) file of the repository and it didn't changed anything so I suspect it is not the right one.

Anyway here is the code `train(...)` in a file `model.py`:

```
...

import rasa_nlu
from rasa_nlu import components, utils, config
from rasa_nlu.components import Component, ComponentBuilder
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig, override_defaults
from rasa_nlu.persistor import Persistor
from rasa_nlu.training_data import TrainingData, Message
from rasa_nlu.utils import create_dir, write_json_to_file

...

class Trainer(object):
    """Trainer will load the data and train all components.

    Requires a pipeline specification and configuration to use for
    the training."""

    # Officially supported languages (others might be used, but might fail)
    SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ["de", "en"]

    def __init__(self,
                 cfg,  # type: RasaNLUModelConfig
                 component_builder=None,  # type: Optional[ComponentBuilder]
                 skip_validation=False  # type: bool
                 ):
        # type: (...) -> None

        self.config = cfg
        self.skip_validation = skip_validation
        self.training_data = None  # type: Optional[TrainingData]

        if component_builder is None:
            # If no builder is passed, every interpreter creation will result in
            # a new builder. hence, no components are reused.
            component_builder = components.ComponentBuilder()

        # Before instantiating the component classes, lets check if all
        # required packages are available
        if not self.skip_validation:
            components.validate_requirements(cfg.component_names)

        # build pipeline
        self.pipeline = self._build_pipeline(cfg, component_builder)

    ...

    def train(self, data, **kwargs):
        # type: (TrainingData) -> Interpreter
        """Trains the underlying pipeline using the provided training data."""
        self.training_data = data

        context = kwargs  # type: Dict[Text, Any]

        for component in self.pipeline:
            updates = component.provide_context()
            if updates:
                context.update(updates)

        # Before the training starts: check that all arguments are provided
        if not self.skip_validation:
            components.validate_arguments(self.pipeline, context)

        # data gets modified internally during the training - hence the copy
        working_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
        for i, component in enumerate(self.pipeline):
            logger.info("Starting to train component {}"
                        "".format(component.name))
            component.prepare_partial_processing(self.pipeline[:i], context)
            print("before train")
            updates = component.train(working_data, self.config,
                                      **context)
            logger.info("Finished training component.")
            print("before updates")
            if updates:
                context.update(updates)
        return Interpreter(self.pipeline, context)
```

And the output is

```
before train
before updates
before train
before updates
before train
before updates
before train
before updates
before train
before updates
before train
before updates
before train
Fitting 2 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 12 fits
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
before updates
trainer.persist:
```

You can see here the warnings which I want to catch and modify to know the origin `UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.`

Therefore, can you see where does this warnings come from? What calls for `sklearn/metrics/classification.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documented issue on the Rasa NLU repository. I would recommend following these issues or adding your comments there for resolution. One is marked as help wanted, meaning they are looking for a community contribution to address it.

- [Training on demo-rasa.json results in UndefinedMetricWarning](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/288)
- [Show name of intent(s) that lack enough train examples](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/431)

The tl:dr on why the warning occurs from the first issue linked above:

> so the warning is just a warning. It indicates that there are too few training examples for one / some of the intents. Adding more examples will fix this (thats why adding duplicates will remove this warning, but really you should be adding different examples).

**If you want the warning to go away add more training data. Use the evaluation.py script to find the intents that are lacking.**

From the warning message you can see it is produced from `sklearn/metrics/classification.py` which is this file [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L871).

Comment: Thanks for the references. Sounds cool, I definitely want to show name of intent(s) that lack enough train examples but still haven't found what triggers `classification.py`

Comment: I would look here, where it is training the intent classification, which is using sklearn https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py#L110

Comment: Yes, exactly, it seems that it is [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) in the `_create_classifier` function that is culprit. It raises the warning when we call for its `fit` function. I'm going to try to catch the warning according to the intent