# How to catch what triggers sklearn.GridSearchCV.fit() warnings?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, warnings, rasa-nlu

In a [function of rasa_nlu](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py#L110) they are calling for [`GridSearchCV.fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) with `clf.fit()` and it raises some warnings I would like to catch and modify to know what triggers them:

```
Fitting 2 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 12 fits
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/rasaenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
```

Here is how `GridSearchCV` is constructed:

```
cv_splits = self._num_cv_splits(y) #when I printed it out it gave me "2", I was expected something more related to the labels

GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1,
                probability=True,
                class_weight='balanced'),
            param_grid=tuned_parameters,
            n_jobs=num_threads,
            cv=cv_splits,
            scoring='f1_weighted',
            verbose=1)
```

Where `y` are the `labels` which have been transformed to numbers

```
y: [1 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3]

labels: ['greet', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'laughing', 'laughing']
```

Ideally I would like to grab which of these triggered the warnings.

#### Update

Until now I tried to get the origin, I still have not found a way to capture the warning:

```
 fit_result = self.clf.fit (X, y)
 y_pred = self.clf.predict (X)
 print ("set (y) -set (y_pred): \ n", set (y) -set (y_pred))
```

But it just gives me an empty set `set ()`

Is it also necessary to use `.predict (X)`? Is it different from the results of `clf.fit ()`?

Comment: These are the true labels. These warnings come from the predicted labels. Your model is not predicting some some the labels (not even once) and hence the warnings

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the comment, I just want to catch the warning and try to figure out which labels caused it. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you getting these warnings on multiple runs of your code?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just continuing the conversation or updating your question on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706605/modifying-warnings-that-seems-to-come-from-nowhere

Comment: Maybe this will help if you are trying to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162506/undefinedmetricwarning-f-score-is-ill-defined-and-being-set-to-0-0-in-labels-wi

Comment: @CalebKeller I was thinking accepting your answer to my question which was on where are the warnings trigered in rasa_nlu, this question was rather on how to try, catch and modify these warnings from sklearn

Comment: Hopefully the link I gave helps.

Comment: @CalebKeller, yes that was exactly the location. I'm now diving in the second link you're providing to try to find a way to catch these intents that are never predicted

Comment: @CalebKeller from the description of [`fit(X, y=None, groups=None, **fit_params)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), as far as `X` is described as _array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]

    Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features._ maybe I could do something from here when I don't have eough samples for a feature? I don't know how much samples I need for a feature though. I have not find a way to do ̀set(y_test) - set(y_pred)` as they do in the link you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177523/discussion-between-marine1-and-caleb-keller).

Comment: @VivekKumar, sorry, I tried to answer you in the chat but wasn't able to invite you in :/

Comment: I believe the warnings cannot be suppressed using the many suggestions on SO is because of `n_jobs=n_threads`. If you set `n_jobs` to 1 and suppress the warnings using something like `simplefilter` it should work (if your goal is to suppress them, but handling them should be similar). I have the same problem with multiple threads but I'm still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To start off [here is the code](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py#L130) that executes the grid search in Rasa NLU's sklearn intent classifier:

```
self.clf.fit(X, y)
```

I was able to completely suppress the warning if I did this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    self.clf.fit(X, y)
```

The filter warnings function has many more options if you want to limit the warnings caught to specific modules or line numbers. [Look here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter).

The best way I could find to catch the warning and do something with it was to actually raise the warning to an error. Catch the error and do whatever I wanted to after that.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("error")

    try:
        self.clf.fit(X, y)
    except:
        ... do some code ...
```

but keep in mind doing this means that the fit doesn't get persisted and would need to be called again after you're extra code. Not too bad on small trainings sets, but quite annoying on large ones.

---

That being said after digging into this and exploring the cause of the error, it truly seems like something that can be ignored by most people or better yet ignored and replaced with a warning on intents that have only 2 training examples. If you notice in your example sklearn prints out:

> Fitting 2 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 12 fits

and then you got six warnings about f-score. It's likely that one entire fold is failing to predict your label with only two examples.

In your example you gave 40 examples. But then that 40 gets split into a training and testing sets. In the case of your intent with only 2 examples, one will go into the training set and one will go into the test set.

I recreated a similar dataset to yours, just based on labels and here where the folds created:

```
TRAIN: [1 1 0 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 2] TEST: [3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 0 3 2 2 2]
TRAIN: [3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 0 3 2 2 2] TEST: [1 1 0 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 2]
```

It's not hard to believe that the test set would mis-classify that 0 as another label. And if they did then the f-score would be ill-defined.

There are several good Stack Overflow posts on this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758800/1408476). If a particular label has no true positives in the predicted set then it causes a zero divided by zero. So therefore sklearn sets it to 0.

Comment: Yes, `try` and `except` with warnings as errors was my first idea but it does mean that `fit` does not get persisted indeed. So there is no way to find out what started the f-score to be ill-defined afterwards rather than remove the problem upstream? In this case my idea is to propose a table parsing to launch a warning on intents that have only 2 training examples and to remove warnings from sklearn. I will make a PR proposal soon.

Comment: I think you can move it upstream, but only by modifying sklearn code and implementing something there. Keep in mind that the f-score isn't necessarily ill defined on all fits so a warning saying to add more training data for a particular intent may or may not be necessary. That's why I was advocating for ignoring this particular error and replacing it with a "low amounts of training data can produce un-expected results" type warning when few example are provided for any one intent.

Comment: Sounds interesting for sklearn but it's their responsibility. Okay, I will modify my attempt a bit for a `warnings.warn("low amounts of training data, can produce un-expected results")`. Yet someone can have lot amounts of training data and only few on some intents and he could not understand this specific message? Maybe we should go back to GitHub as well.